# sql two different aggregate function in having clause and select clause

Tags: sql

I am praticing some sql questions and I had to find the max number with no duplicates. I am a little confused about why this query does not work. Shouldn't the having clause finish and then the max() inside the select operation? instead the max does not do anything at all which i dont understand. please example with how the compiler/server sees it.

```
select max(num)
from mynumbers
group by num
having count(num)=1;
```

```
Table schema
+-------------+------+
| Column Name | Type |
+-------------+------+
| num         | int  |
+-------------+------+
```

expected:

| max(num) |
| --- |
| 6 |

results:

```
| max(num) |
| -------- |
| 1        |
| 4        |
| 5        |
| 6        |
```

Comment: Why did you include `having count(num)=1`? What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: Query is returning Max(num) for each unique num, which really doesn't make sense. If you just want the maximum num, don't GROUP BY and HAVING is not needed. `SELECT Max(num) As MaxNum FROM mynumbers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here is,  `max(num)` is applied after the grouping by `GROUP BY` and the filtering by `HAVING` have taken place; therefore, it is finding the maximum number within each group of unique numbers and then filters out groups where the frequencies are more than 1 AND not the maximum unique number in the num column which you are really after.

to get the maximum value among the num values with no duplicates, you can use a subquery to select the distinct num values where the count is equal to 1 and then apply the `MAX()` function to these unique values like this:

```
SELECT MAX(num) AS max_num
FROM (
    SELECT num
    FROM mynumbers
    GROUP BY num
    HAVING COUNT(num) = 1
) AS unique_nums;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` applies to the whole query, not only to the `HAVING`

What you are doing, `HAVING` omitted, is: for each separate value of `num`, get the `max` (which is that value itself since your `GROUP BY` clause keeps different values of `num` separate i.e. records with `1`, `4`, `5` and `6` are not mixed in the same group for the calculation of `max(num)`).

If by "*max number with no duplicates*", you mean the maximum of the values that have no duplicate in `mytable` (clear wording is important because I would argue the actual result you share in your question does show no duplicate), then you need to put the `MAX` outside of the scope covered by your `GROUP BY`, for instance with a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(num)
FROM (
    SELECT   num
    FROM     mynumbers
    GROUP BY num
    HAVING   COUNT(num) = 1
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `MAX` is applied after grouping. But you don't need a subquery, you can just use `TOP` or `LIMIT` (depending on your syntax).

```sql
select top (1)
  mn.num
from mynumbers mn
group by
  mn.num
having count(*) = 1
order by num desc;
```

Note that `count(somevalue)` does not return the number of distinct values, it just counts the number of non-nulls. If the value is not nullable then it's the same as `count(*)`.